# My hooks aren't opening and closing my modals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm new to react and redux, I'm trying to do things the newish hooks way and running into issues opening and closing a Modal using a redux state.

Basically, as soon as my page loads, the modal opens, even though the initial state in the slice is set to false and the close button in the modal footer doesn't close it.

I'm trying to learn from the example that compiles from `npx create-react-app redux-demo --template redux` but I'm clearly missing something.

Thanks!

**AffinityModal.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label, Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter, ModalHeader, Row, } from 'reactstrap';
import { affinOpen, toggleAffinAsync } from '../modalSlice'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function AffinityModal() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
return (
  <Modal isOpen={affinOpen} toggle={() => dispatch(toggleAffinAsync())}>
  <ModalHeader>
      <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Ingredient Affinity</h5>
      <Button data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" className="close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&#xD7;</span>
      </Button>
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Row>
              <div className="col-12">
                <Label for="mainIngName" className="col-form-label">Main Ingredient:</Label>
              </div>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <div className="col-12">
                <Input readOnly type="text" id="mainIngName"></Input>
              </div>
            </Row>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Row>
              <div className="col-12">
                <Label for="added-ing-text" className="col-form-label">Combines Well With:</Label>
              </div>
            </Row>
            <Row id="secondaryIngs">
              <div className="col-10">
                <Input type="text" id="added-ing-text" className="secIngInputs"></Input>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2">
                <Button id="ingPlusButton">+</Button>
              </div>
            </Row>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </ModalBody><ModalFooter>
      <Button data-dismiss="modal" onClick={() => dispatch(toggleAffinAsync())} color="secondary">Close</Button>
      <Button id="submitNewIngButton" color="primary" className="submitButton">Submit</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
</Modal >
)
```

}

export default AffinityModal

**modalSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const modalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'openAffinityModal',
  initialState: {
    isAffinityModalOpen: false,
    isRecipeModalOpen: false
  },
  reducers: {
    toggleAffinityModal: state => {
      state.isAffinityModalOpen = !state.isAffinityModalOpen
    },
    toggleRecipeModal: state => {
      state.isRecipeModalOpen = !state.isRecipeModalOpen
    }
  }
})

export const { toggleAffinityModal, toggleRecipeModal } = modalSlice.actions;

export const toggleAffinAsync = isAffinityModalOpen => dispatch => {
    dispatch(toggleAffinityModal);
  };

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: `useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)`
//useSelector((state) => state.openAffinityModal.isAffinityModalOpen)
export const affinOpen = state => state.openAffinityModal.isAffinityModalOpen;

export default modalSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `toggleAffinAsync` at all.  Just use the regular action creator `toggleAffinityModal`.

`affinOpen` is a selector function.  It is not a value.  Right now your `Modal` is always open because you are passing this function to the `isOpen` prop and a `function` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) when cast to a `boolean`.

In order to get the `boolean` value from the state, you need to *call* `affinOpen` with `useSelector`.

```
function AffinityModal() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isOpen = useSelector(affinOpen);
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={() => dispatch(toggleAffinityModal())}>
...
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-modal-open-2z8us?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate this.  After making those changes I'm now getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAffinityModalOpen' of undefined.  I'm looking at your sandbox to see what we're doing differently for what I should change.

Comment: That's probably coming from `state.openAffinityModal.isAffinityModalOpen` so the `undefined` would be `state.openAffinityModal`.  You would want to make sure that in your `configureStore` you are setting this reducer to the `openAffinityModal` property.

Comment: that got it tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the original version from the reactstrap docs?

```
const toggle = () => dispatch(toggleAffinAsync());

<Modal isOpen={affinOpen} toggle={toggle} >
...
</Modal>
```

Comment: that's basically what I have for toggle but just to check I moved it to a variable as in your example and still no dice.